# Entity Framework table Mapped to an Association with No Table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, associations

I created a table in SQL that just contained 2 foreign keys, Which Linked a single Bulk upload entry to many titles.  After updating my edmx model.

I noticed there is no table in the diagram.
Just an Association mapped between my title table and my bulkupload table.

There is no table in the diagram so I cannot delete the table.
I cannot add things to the table because there is no connection in the C# Code.  '

Does anybody have information on why this is happening and how I can fix and add this table so its able to add entries to it?

Comment: This is a "many-to-many".  No, unless there is an attribute on the relationship, there will be no table in the diagram.  you would delete the association.  If you were to add an attribute....on the ~relationship, there would be an extra table.  For a generic example, think employee-to-jobtitle (many to many) with a start-date of when a specific emp-for-a-jobtitle started.  Aka, "Sam" became a "Manager" on "01/01/2015".

Comment: So to sum up what your say I have to add an additional field to the table?  If I left it just as an association is there a way to add to the associations through entities?

Comment: No, you don't have to add a new attribute.  If only the relationship(s) exist, then your edmx will not have an extra table BUT there will be a table in the database with 2 FK's in it.

Comment: EDMX is not a database diagram tool.  It is a objects and relationships tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave it as an association if you'd like.  To add things to you junction table you add things to your Icollection so in pseducode:

```
BulkEntry.Titles.add(TitleToAdd)
```